# QR algorithm repeating eigenvalues

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical

Can QR algorithm find repeat eigenvalues (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) ? I.e. Does it support the case when not all N eigen value for real matrix N x N are distinct?

How extend QR algorithm to support finding complex eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

In principle yes. It will work if the eigenvalues are really all eigenvalues, i.e., the algebraic and geometric multiplicity are the same.

If the multiple eigenvalue occurs in an Jordan-block of size `s`, then the unavoidable floating point error during the iteration will almost surely result in a star-shaped perturbation into an eigenvalue cluster with relative error of size `mu^(1/s)` where `mu` is the machine constant of the floating point data type.

---

The reason this happens is that on the irreducible invariant subspace corresponding to a Jordan block of size `s` the characteristic polynomial of the reduction of the linear operator to this subspace has is `(λ-λ[j])^s`. During the computation this gets perturbed to `(λ-λ[j])^s+μq(λ)` which in first approximation has roots close to `λ[j]+μ^(1/s)*z[k]`, where `z[k]` denotes the `s` roots of `0=z^s+q(λ[k])`. What the perturbation function `q` is is quite random, accumulated floating point truncation errors, and depends on details of the method.

Comment: I have sandbox code with Linear Algebra algorithms. Hope return to it from 2 months, right now I don't have enough time. p.s. Can you provide a reference to your notes or somebody else notes who analyzed this situation. p.p.s I'm from Russia, Moscow. Even Vera Kublanovskaya has some papers about it, but they have been written for people with great mathematical background it is very hard to read them at least for me.

Comment: I do not have any sources at hand, in general this is some extension of the perturbation theory of polynomial roots. I've added a semi-correct simple justification on what one should expect to see.